# How do i add a custom configuration in mono develop?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I am coding a bit of C# at my school in Mono, using monoDevelop as a IDE on Ubuntu.

I can run my application by doing Run --> Run with --> Custom configuration --> checking off "Use external console" --> advanced --> Setting Execute in .NET Runtime to mono instead of (Default Runtime) --> Run ... When then executes alright, i want to make this a custom configuration though, that is saved so whenever i press run i does exactly this. I cannot find any custom configuration options though, and i cannot seem to find any plugins that offers this either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that you are using a version of MonoDevelop before version 6.1.

Support for run configurations was added in [Xamarin Studio 6.1](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.1/xamarin.studio_6.1/#Run_Configurations), so that will be in MonoDevelop 6.1.

[image: Run Configuration in Project Options]

Adding a run configuration with a recent version of MonoDevelop will create a .user file named after your project's .csproj file which has custom run configuration information.